# How to detect key pressed in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, typescript

What would be the semantically equivalent syntax in typescript to the following line in javascript

```js
// Some knockout event handler
myFunc(data: string, evt: Event) {
    // If enter or tab key up were detected add the excuse to the collection
    if (evt.enterKey || evt.which == 9) {
        // Do Something
    }
}
```

The trouble I'm having here is unlike regular javascript event, typescript Event class does not have a property `enterKey` or `which`. So how do I detect which key is being pressed without getting typescript compile error and the ugly red wiggly underline?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You need to use the more specialised event type `KeyboardEvent`, as shown below:

```
myFunc(data : string, evt : KeyboardEvent)
```

If you want to also remove errors for `evt.enterKey` you'll need to add it by extending the interface - although I'm not aware that this is a real property as it isn't technical a control key, like `CTRL`, `SHIFT` or `ALT`, which all have properties on the event:

```
interface KeyboardEvent {
    enterKey: boolean;
}
```

Answer (score 38):

For React Users

```
  private onKeyDown = (e: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
    console.log(e.key)
  }
```

where `HTMLDivElement` is the type of whichever element `onKeyDown` is attached to.

Here is the [List](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/global.d.ts#L32) (from line 32-90) of all supported HTML elements.

Answer (score 7):

You need register the event, for example:

```
class EventHandler {
    static RegisterKeyPress(input: string){
        document.getElementById(input).addListener('keypress', (e: KeyboardEvent) =>{
           //You have yout key code here
            console.log(e.keyCode);
        }
    }
}
```

Happy coding!

Comment: Key code is deprecated property.

Answer (score 2):

In React:

Declare global interface:

```
declare global {
  interface WindowEventMap {
    keydown: KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>
  }
}
```

Then just use it:

```
 const handleUserKeyPress = (event: KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const { key } = event
      if (key === "Escape") {
        // do something
      }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('keydown', handleUserKeyPress)

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('keydown', handleUserKeyPress)
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 2):

I am sharing my experience. hope this will be useful to someone.

If you are using an `EventListener`, you cannot simply pass `KeyboardEvent` as a parameter. I used `as` keyword to mitigate the type errors.

```
myElement.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    if ((e as KeyboardEvent).key === 'Enter') {
        // do something..
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may like [Keystrokes](https://github.com/RobertWHurst/Keystrokes). It's a small library written in TypeScript for doing this exact sort of thing.

*Bind a single key*

```js
import { bindKey, bindKeyCombo } from '@rwh/keystrokes'

const handlePressed = () =>
  console.log('pressed a')

bindKey('a', handlePressed)
// -- or --
bindKey('a', {
  onPressed: handlePressed,
  onPressedWithRepeat: handlePressedRepeat,
  onReleased: handleReleased,
})
```

*Bind a key combo*

```js
const handlePressed = () =>
  console.log('pressed a, released a, pressed b and c in any order')

bindKeyCombo('a, b+c', handlePressed)
// -- or --
bindKeyCombo('a, b+c', {
  onPressed: handlePressed,
  onPressedWithRepeat: handlePressedRepeat,
  onReleased: handleReleased,
})
```

This example just shows a simple handler bound to a key or a key combo, but you can also pass an object instead of a single function with a handler for onPressed, onPressedWithRepeat, and/or onReleased, all of which are optional.

There is also support packages for [Vue](https://github.com/RobertWHurst/Keystrokes#using-keystrokes-with-vue) and [React](https://github.com/RobertWHurst/Keystrokes#using-keystrokes-with-react).