# Checking if control/command key is currently pressed in VS Extensions

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In my extension, I would like to check in a certain function, if the control (or command) key is currently pressed. How is that possible? I couldn't find any field that exposes this information.

Comment: What is the extension doing? When do you want to get the key status?

Comment: It's here: https://github.com/nuke-build/vscode/blob/master/source/extension.ts#L48 Depending on whether control/command key is pressed, I want to set `noDebug` to `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the below article

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/patterns-and-principles

It says

> Visual Studio Code has a very rich extensibility model and there are many ways to extend the tool. However, we do not provide direct access to the underlying UI DOM to extension writers. With VS Code, we’re continually trying to optimize use of the underlying web technologies to deliver an always available, highly responsive editor and we will continue to tune our use of the DOM as these technologies and our product evolve. To maintain performance and compatibility, we run extensions in their own host process and prevent direct access to the DOM. VS Code also includes a built-in set of UI components for common scenarios such as IntelliSense, so that these experiences are consistent across programming languages and extensions and extension developers do not need to build their own.
>
> We realize that this approach may initially feel restrictive to extension developers. We’re always looking for ways to improve our extensibility model and expand the capabilities available to extensions. We look forward to hearing your feedback and ideas.

This means your extension code doesn't run the in editor window context at all. And you can't hack into the webview as the extension api doesn't provide it. So you need to open a Feature request with VScode team and ask them to expose either the last keyboard event or atleast the status of `Shift`, `Ctrl` and `alt` keys. Currently they just discard it and throw it away (if no editor is open) else they send it to the monaco editor before checking for any shortcut combination

[image: Throw event away]

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24108197/how-to-detect-key-pressed-in-typescript) might be of use. With this approach you could track a key down event and then if the key code is equal to command (91 or 93 on Safari/Chrome, 224 on Firefox) or control. From there, you could put in your functionality if this returns as true, or however you want to structure it

Comment: How does this have any relation to VSCode?

Comment: @TarunLalwani , Matthias is asking about writing a method for an extension to be used inside of VSCode, so this answer is talking about the code that may be of use inside of said extension, from my impression at least

Comment: Nope, it that extension has no access to the keyboard at all. I am writing a answer now with more details. Your code is not applicable as such

Comment: Please see the answer I just posted and you will understand why your link is not applicable here

Answer (score 0):

This does not directly answer your question but maybe helps solving your problem:
Your extension could contribute two different commands: For example first command `myextension.runTarget` (`noDebug=true`) and  `myextension.debugTarget` (`noDebug=false`). In addition your extension can contribute keybindings that bind those two commands to different hotkeys, for instance <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> and only <kbd>F5</kbd>.

Looks like vscode itself does it the same way (screenshot of keybindings view):
[image: Keybinding screenshot]