# How can I detect when the tab key is pressed?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am writing an extension for vscode and would like to react to the user pressing the tab key. How can I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect key pressed in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24108197/how-to-detect-key-pressed-in-typescript)

Comment: Unfortunately no. It needs to be compatible with the VSCode API.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm writing an extension and need to capture tab and/or escape. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Here a small solution of how to do that in dumb component

```js
const handleKeyDown = (e) => {
    if (e.key === "Tab") {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log("tab is pressed");
    }
  }

<input type="text" onKeyDown={handleKeyDown} />
```

Comment: Thanks. But I don't think this solution will work in a vscode extension.

Comment: Why not, my only code editor I am using now is VS code....so not sure what you are trying to say.

Comment: I am not coding in VSCode, I am creating an extension (plugin) for vscode. I'm pretty sure you cannot capture key presses that way.

Comment: This is keyDown ;)

Comment: Apart from custom webviews, you can't manipulate the DOM in VSCode extensions. So no way to set any `onKeyDown`.

Comment: Instead of telling what is not working, you should come up with a better solution....@Gama11